# C++ LinkTime/CompileTime Generate Function Offset From Start Of .Text Section Or Other Reference Point

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker, function-pointers, portable-executable

So I have a need for a way to get an offset of a function from its PE files .text region/whatever section it is in, or within reference to another function within the file.

I'd like to do something similar:

```c++
void func_two()
{
    /*...*/
}

void call_our_function()
{
    /*...*/
}

void main_loop()
{
    constexpr offset_of_two = (int)&func_two - (int)&call_our_function;
    
    // calls func_two
    (decltype(&func_two)(offset_of_two + (int)&call_our_function))();
    
    /* OR : */
    
    void* text_region = find_pe_text_region_start();
    constexpr offset_from_text = get_offset_from_linker_somehow();
    
    // calls func_two
    (decltype(&func_two)(offset_from_text + (int)&offset_from_text))(); 
}
```

constexpr doesn't allow this. I'm assuming its because the linker sets these values for func address/etc at link-time. However I know that link time theoretically could do this, otherwise export tables and RVAs in the PE file wouldn't work. I know I could export them and parse the export table, but that doesn't particularly work for my use case.

Anybody know of any ways to solve this problem, without calculating them at runtime? Maybe a plugin for the linker, however I doubt MSVC supports that. Very specific use I have here.

Answer (score 1):

Function pointers are a separate class of pointers and you can't only cast them to other function pointers. They may be larger then `uintptr_t` and certainly will be larger than `int` on common 64bit architectures. Using `int` is totally UB. Using `uintptr_t` would at least bring it up to implementation defined behavior.

But you are right that the values are only going to be available at link time. Until you link the compiler has no idea where in memory the functions will end up and thus can't know the offsets between them.

So there is no way of making this constexpr. It should become link time evaluated though. The object format (at least ELF) allows encoding the difference between 2 symbols and other simple math and the linker will compute the actual value at link time. There should be no runtime overhead for this.

PS: declare the offsets global and check if the resulting binary contains them as constants or computes them in the init_array / ctors. The local variables might compute them at runtime because that doesn't require defining an extra constant.